# What happens after Deleting then inserting within data page?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, delete-row, truncate

Assume I had table called `Employee`, this table has million records , Then I used the following Query:

```
Delete From Employee;
```

**There are some facts:**

1) All rows will be deleted.

2) All data pages that associated to this table will be empty

3) These empty pages are not deallocated. (`Truncate` is doing this)

4) Depends to this [article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189245(v=sql.105).aspx),  the associated space cannot be reused by other objects in the database.

now my question is ..

What happens with new records , is the new records saved in these free pages, or sql server engine creates a new data pages for inserting operation althought there are free pages before via deleting process.

I know the differance between `Delete` and `Truncate` , but I am confused with the new records if there are free data pages before for the same object (table).

Comment: 3) and 4) are mostly wrong, those pages are deallocated and the space in them is reusable. The "not reusable" restriction applies only to heap tables and even then only if a table lock isn't taken. Under normal circumstances, you're deleting from a clustered index.

Comment: what about heap tables ? is it inserting into new data pages or the same exist free data pages ?

Comment: If any empty-but-allocated pages remain they are still reusable for that heap table, just not for other objects. The engine may or may not use them for any particular insert as opposed to a new page (this also depends on locking and parallel transactions), but it is not normally the case that repeated deletes and inserts will cause a heap table to grow without bounds due to unused pages. That said, the normal operation for a heap table is to either truncate it or to delete only with a table lock and these are the only setups I have practical experience with.

Comment: appreciate your comments, thanks pro.